# How to remove repeated value?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

How to remove repeated value?

Example:

```
12345
12345
12345
12346
12346
12346
12347
12347
12347
```

Required output:

```
12345
12346
12347
```

Comment: Side note please avoid "new here"/"thank you" in your post.

Comment: is that a list, or string ? what is the type of your input

Comment: Judging from your required output, you already figured out how to remove repeated values. You should try writing a program to do it for you though

Comment: Output of what? What is "12345 12345 ..."? A string with multiple lines, a list of strings or ints, a string or int array, a file, something else?

Answer (score 2):

If type of your input is a string, you can use `Join`, `Split` and `Distinct` like this, split the input by *white-space* get unique items then concatenate them again using `Join` method:

```
var input = "12345 12345 12345 12346 12346 12346 12347 12347 12347";

var output = string.Join(" ", input.Split().Distinct());
```

If your input is a `List` then just use `Distinct` method which returns you a sequence with unique items.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an `IEnumerable<T>` collection as input, use `Distinct` method from LINQ:

```
var result = source.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a collection on numbers you can just do:

```
list.Distinct();
```

to convert to a `List` just add `ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "12345 12345 12345 12346 12346 12346 12347 12347 12347";

var output = string.Join(" ", input.Split(' ').Distinct());
```